# Pass Javascript Variable To C# Code Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to get value from javascript to C# code behind ? I have an idea with the code below. In javascript code I want to assign the value of "HiddenField" Control with string value and then I want to take this value from "HiddenField" in code behind. But with this code I cannot do it. Can you tell me how to make it ?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        document.getElementById('HiddenField').value = "active";
        console.log(<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>)
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value="5" Visible="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `ClientID` property of control to get actual element ID in DOM.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
                document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField.ClientID%>').value = "active";
                console.log(document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField.ClientID%>').value)
        });
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value="5" Visible="true" />
```

Comment: It worked. Is this the prefer way to pass javascript variable to C# ?

Comment: or `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: if you are updating values from client side on some logic, than this is the preferred way.

Comment: @TheChampp as Stefan mentioned, if you used ClientIDMode to static, than no need to ClientID but this property is available in asp.net 4.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Control ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

```
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField.ClientID%>').value = "active";
```

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id
>   attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID
>   property. The ClientID value is often used to access the HTML element
>   in client script by using the document.getElementById method.

Answer (score 0):

Then send the Hidden value through the javascript function as a variable while calling the controller

Surely works,

Cheers
Phani*

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at mshtml
As far as I know you call with this C# functions from your javascript code ;-)